# Unable to get JNDI connectivity using Spring Boot 2 and Tomcat 8.5.38 (Not Embedded Tomcat)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, tomcat, jndi

Trying to establish a database connectivity using Springboot and Tomcat 8.5.38 JNDI configuration(Not Embedded config). Always getting deployment getting failure getting entityManagerFactory bean issues, like below stack trace. This happens when trying to connect using JNDI, if remove JNDI , the basic controllers are working fine.

tried to connect to the database in normal way like below and it worked as expected.

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/test
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=****
```

## server.xml

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    maxActive="8" maxIdle="0" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/test" password="root" username="root" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="9080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" copyXML="true">


        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

## Context.xml

---

```
 <Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <ResourceLink auth="Container" name="jdbc/test" global="jdbc/test" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

## application.properties

---

```
*******************************************************
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/test

************* Hibernate Configuration ******************

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

## POM.xml

---

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
             <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
             <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

## Entity

---

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
     @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
}
```

## Repository

---

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

## Configuraion class

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.sudeep.jpa")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sudeep.jpa.modal")
public class PersistenceJNDIConfig {

     @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
          throws NamingException {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em 
              = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(dataSource());
            em.setPackagesToScan("com.sudeep.jpa.modal");
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
            em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
            // rest of entity manager configuration
            return em;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
            return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.jndi-name"));
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {

            return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        }
        @Bean
        public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
            return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        }
        final Properties additionalProperties() {
            final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
            hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
            return hibernateProperties;
        }
```

## springBootInit

---

```
@Configuration
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(JpaApplication.class);
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## Controller

---

```
@RestController
    public class HelloController {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepo userRepo;
    @GetMapping("/get")
            public List<User> getUser() {


                return userRepo.findAll();
            }
```

Expecting successful connectivity ad clear loggers

## Stack Trace

---

```
   11-Aug-2019 11:18:21.548 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.sudeep.jpa.PersistenceJNDIConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.getPersistenceProviderRootPackage(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:160)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 29 more

11-Aug-2019 11:18:21.552 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [F:\Softwares\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.38\webapps\JPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do your have a "Resource" definition in <tomcat_home>/conf/server.xml file corresponding to you spring.datasource.jndi-name?

Comment: Yes i have , and configure the context.xml properly, I edited that in my question tag

Comment: Can you paste full context.xml and server.xml please.

Comment: copied full server.xml and context.xml

Comment: ok. what is the the path after "Error deploying configuration descriptor .." in your error attachment file (or better add the full stack trace of the error) please.

Comment: Added Stack trace in last

Comment: hope the last useful contents of : JPA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml and these two : <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

Comment: tried to deploy using tomcat manager now getting entity manager issues updated the stack trace,

Answer (score 0):

Finally Started Working. Below are the code tweaks

First,

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
    }
}
```

I made a big mistake in the initial stage of the application development

Second,

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sudeep.jpa.modal")
```

I mapped Modal classes instead of Repository. Later i changed to:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sudeep.jpa.repository")
```

Later this stated working , Happy Learning... :)